# Spring Boot 2.0 - Validation don`t work

Tags: validation, spring-boot

I created form which I would like to validate with Spring Tools. Unfortunately the form has been passed with errors. I don't know what is the problem. I tryed add to pom spring-boot-starter-validation, but it's steel don`t work. Could you tell me where is error(s)?

pom:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>library</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Controller (part of the save record):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveEmployee(@Valid EmployeeDTO empl, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addEmployee";
    }
    employeeService.save(empl);

    return "redirect:/employees";
}
```

EmployeeDTO:

```
package com.xyz.dto;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

    public class EmployeeDTO {

    private Integer id = null;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 150)
    private String street;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 150)
    private String city;

@NotNull
@Email
private String email;
//getters and setters
```

Comment: Your `saveEmployee` method is handling GET requests and your front end code is probably posting the form. If your method even being called? What do you see in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Yes, the method is called. Parameters are sent. When I debug code (in Java) and pub breakpoin in metod "if (result.hasErrors()" I get "result:"org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors" "

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar probem. After updating to Spring Boot 2.0 validation just wouldn't work. The problem was with method

```
@InitBinder(BasketCommandService.COMMAND_NAME)
protected final void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(validator);
}
```

that couldn't be proxied.
This is part of console output from when building my project:

```
2018-07-09 14:26:15.593  INFO 18600 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [protected final void cz.<companyName>.core.web.shop.orderprocess.AbstractOrderProcessController.initBinder(org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
```

The sollution was to look at all the warnings that looked like the one above and remove the "final" word from affected methods.